# Sort Array from text file alphabetically then out put to another file java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, text-files

I'm doing an assignment where I need to read text from a file using the scanner. then write it in a loop that makes a string array. and use arrays. sort method to sort the array alphabetically. after that, it prints the array to an output file. also has to show this on the command line. the sentence on the input file is "to be or not to be that is the question" it has to be displayed word by word each word on a new line. this is what I have so far but the sort method isn't sorting it's just reading the array?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                String[] str = {input.next().toString()};
                Arrays.sort(str);

                for (String stringArray : str) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

in case maybe i dont fully understand what im asking this is the instructions on what the full program has to do in the end. right now im just trying to get sort method to work.

Create an array of Strings to store the words read from the input file.  You can assume that the input file will contain 10000 words or fewer.

Use Scanner to read the input file.  In the header of a loop, call the hasNext() method on the Scanner object.  As long as the file has more strings and the array has not been filled, keep doing the loop.

In the body of the loop, call the next() method on the Scanner object.  This method returns a String.  Convert this to lower case (there’s a method of String that does this – see the API for String), then assign the lower-case word to an element of the String array.

When the loop has finished reading the file, call the method Arrays.sort(…) , passing your String array as the argument to this method.

Write the contents of the sorted array to another file using PrintWriter.  You will need to use a loop to write the elements of your array.  In this loop, write some code to make sure that the same word is not written to the output file more than once.  Use a variable to save the last word that you have written to the file.  Before you write the next word, compare it to the last one, and write it only if it is different.

Comment: Please provide example input/output. Currently you are reading **each** line, then sorting a **singleton array** (which obviously does nothing), then writing that line back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think this is what you trying for (but if file is big try to use some Sorted  collection instead):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
     List<String> inputText = new ArrayList();
     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         inputText.add(input.nextLine());             
     }
     Arrays.sort(inputText);
     for (String str : inputText) {
          System.out.println(str);
     }            
 }
```

}

Comment: `Arrays.sort(input);` - nope.

Answer (score 3):

Because you read one line, sort it and overwrite it again! And I prefer to read with BufferedReader and add to ArrayList.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("input.txt");
List<String> lines;
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
    lines = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }   
}
Collections.sort(lines);
```

You can add unknown number of items and no need to deal with an array size.

If you really want work with **arrays**, add this line to the end of code:

```
String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

Thanks [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) for a hint.